# use spring cloud config in web application without spring boot

Tags: spring-cloud

i want to know is there any way to use spring cloud config client without spring boot in a spring web application.
i want to use spring cloud config with @Value annotation and i don't like to use spring cloud server rest api in my web application
i have tried what developers said in [Spring Cloud Config Client Without Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28367425/spring-cloud-config-client-without-spring-boot) link but it didn't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Cloud Config Client Without Spring Boot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28367425/spring-cloud-config-client-without-spring-boot)

Comment: actually this link wasn't helpful,because it's a open ended discussion and i want to use spring cloud config client as same as they said in spring cloud config official  documentation

Comment: The rest api is the way to do it without config client.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. You will have to add spring boot but don't have to really use it (we had it working in a non-springboot app). Check this code here https://github.com/4finance/micro-infra-spring/tree/master/micro-infra-spring-config . You don't need a config server then to use the properties. I don't have a code snippet for that but you would have to create manually a spring boot context in your just to make this work. Also check this answer - [Spring Cloud Config Client Without Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28367425/spring-cloud-config-client-without-spring-boot) . Even if you will make it work it doesn't mean that the ordering will be proper.

The suggested solution then is to actually use Spring Boot :)

Answer (score 0):

I provided an answer here : [Spring Cloud Config Client Without Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28367425/spring-cloud-config-client-without-spring-boot/45376158#45376158) that can help you. It's a working prototype to load property sources from Zookeeper using Spring Cloud Config Zookeeper in a webapplication without Spring Boot.