# Initialize spring cloud config client, for SDK development

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

This question is somewhat similar to this [existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28367425/spring-cloud-config-client-without-spring-boot)

I am still trying to navigate or trying to find right spring boot code, which i can customize. I need to develop java SDK which connects with existing config server and provides values to key. This SDK will be used in java applications, which might or might not be spring application. Same SDK will be used by QA for regression testing of config server.

So question is, if given

1. Config server URL
2. application name
3. active profile (no need for label, it will be default master), 
   Can I initialize some config client class which will give me simple methods like *public String getKeyValue(final String key)*

I am looking at source of classes like *ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator*, *CompositePropertySource*, *ConfigClientAutoConfiguration*, *ConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration* etc.

Do I need to build Environment object manually? If yes, how?

Comment: I'm not quite sure where your question is heading. In essence you can access the config server just by URL having the three things given and retrieve in a format you like (yaml, json). So everything you'd need is `HttpUrlConnection` and maybe a JSON library and that's it.

Comment: I am trying to avoid parsing JSON and get values myself. Also client side app can provide cmdLine overriding arguments. To make it perfect, I might end up reinventing wheel. Hence I want to use config client libraries as SDK to config-server.

Comment: But I don't get your aim. Do you want to keep it as low-key as possible or re-use what is there? If first see above comment if second you might not be able to use this without Spring.

Comment: Hi Dan, As I said, it might be duplicate of existing question. To answer you, i need to run this SDK (config client) in non-spring environment. I can add dependencies on spring boot though. I need to override few methods, to customize, how we get values & file contents too. (config server supports serving file contents too)

Answer (score 0):

I have some success. Posting a possible answer for others to further fine tune it.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ConfigSDKApp {

    @Autowired
    public SomeSpringBean someBean = null;

    private static ConfigSDKApp INSTANCE = null;

    public synchronized static ConfigSDKApp getInstance(String[] args) {
        if (null != INSTANCE) {
            return INSTANCE;
        }

        SpringApplication sprApp = new SpringApplication(ConfigSDKApp.class);
    sprApp.setWebEnvironment(false);
    ConfigurableApplicationContext appContext = sprApp.run(args);
    ConfigSDKApp app = appContext.getBean(ConfigSDKApp.class);//new ConfigSDKApp();

        INSTANCE = app;
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

It's kind of singleton class (but public constructor). Hence code smell. 
Also, what if this SDK is running with-in springboot client. ApplicationContext & environment is already initialized.