# Ktor application with spring config server

Tags: ktor

wanted to try some new stuff and decided to build next micro-app in Ktor + Koin + Exposed. Everything looks really nice but I found one problem that is actually destroying the whole idea.

App needs DB access and the connection cannot be stored within repository but should be encrypted on config-server. Every other micro-app is suing spring boot and fetches configs with lib `spring-cloud-config-client` but I don't know if it's even possible to use that somehow from Ktor app. Anyone had the same problem and managed to fix it somehow?

Comment: By "connection", do you mean the credentials for the database? Usually you would have some kind of deploy mechanism that allows you to configure the environment.

Comment: All the connection details - url, username, password should be encrypted and dependant on used profile (dev, prep, prod) - we use spring's config server for that and it's been working great so far.

Comment: From some quick searching I gather that there is no existing integration of spring cloud config for non spring-boot projects.

Answer (score 0):

Cfg4j seems to be an alternative to Spring Cloud Config Server.

https://github.com/cfg4j/cfg4j

Other than that, there are a few articles and some questions on SO about integrating Spring Cloud Config Server with non Spring Boot projects.

[Spring Cloud Config Client Without Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28367425/spring-cloud-config-client-without-spring-boot)

Also, I am working on an external configuration parser for Kotlin and am considering to implement similar functionality.